# In SQLAlchemy, how does the dict update method interact with the ORM?

Tags: python, json, orm, sqlalchemy

So I had a SQLAlchemy Table with a JSON column:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_json_column = db.Column(JSON)
```

And I tried to update the column with the `dict#update` method like so:

```
def foo(my_object, new_params):
    my_object.my_json_column.update(new_params)
    db.session.commit()
```

However, that didn't work. Edit: *What I meant is, the updates weren't being persisted unto the database.*

What did work, was this:

```
def foo(my_object, new_params):
    temp_params = my_object.my_json_column.copy()
    temp_params.update(new_params)
    my_object.my_json_column = new_params
    db.session.commit()
```

I suspect it has something to do with "immutability" or the ORM only notices changes on direct assignment, or something. Does anyone know exactly why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. By default SQLAlchemy doesn't track changes *inside* `dict` attributes. To make it track changes, you can use the [`mutable`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html) extension:

```
class MyTable(db.Model):
    ...
    my_json_column = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSON))
```