# Unable to edit JSON value in PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How do I update a JSONB value for an object in SQLAlchemy using a PostgreSQL?

I am using PostgreSQL 10.1 and SQLAlchemy 1.2.1.

Code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy import Index
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy


Base = declarative_base()

class Email (Base):

    __tablename__ = 'email'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSONB)
    email = Column(String(256), unique=True)

    def __repr__ (self):
        return "< Email %s: %s - %s >" % (self.id, self.email, self.data)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.email


IDXEmailId = Index('idx_email_id', Email.id)
IDXEmailData = Index('idx_email_data', Email.data, postgresql_using='gin')
IDXEmailEmail = Index('idx_email_email', Email.email)


connectionString = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/test'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connectionString, echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
s = Session()
```

Here is an attempt to use the model at console:

```
>>> s.delete(s.query(Email).first())
>>> s.commit()
>>> s.query(Email).count()
0L
>>> a = Email()
>>> a.email = 'test@example.com'
>>> a.data = {'email_type': 'personal'}
>>> s.add(a)
>>> s.commit()
>>> s.query(Email).count()
1L
>>> del a
>>> b = s.query(Email).first()
>>> b
< Email 2: test@example.com - {u'email_type': u'personal'} >
>>> b.__dict__
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x05C67210>, 'data': {u'email_type': u'personal'}, 'email': u'test@example.com', 'id': 2}
>>> b.data['last_contact'] = '2018-03-08'
>>> b
< Email 2: test@example.com - {u'email_type': u'personal', 'last_contact': '2018-03-08'} >
>>> b.data
{u'email_type': u'personal', 'last_contact': '2018-03-08'}
>>> b.email = 'new-email@example.com'
>>> s.commit()
>>> del b
>>> s.query(Email).count()
1L
>>> c = s.query(Email).first()
>>> c
< Email 2: new-email@example.com - {u'email_type': u'personal'} >
>>> c.__dict__
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x05C32490>, 'data': {u'email_type': u'personal'}, 'email': u'new-email@example.com', 'id': 2}
>>> c.data
{u'email_type': u'personal'}
```

Above, I am creating an "Email" object, adding some attributes to it (one an email address, the other some text to be stored in a JSON field) then committing it to the database. This is the only object in the database so for convenience I am retrieving it using .first().

I then update the .data attribute by adding a new key/value pair and commit again. I also update the .email attribute just to show the object is being updated.

When I pull the object out of the database again the .email is updated but the .data is not.

I can't identify what it is I'm doing wrong.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298077/in-sqlalchemy-how-does-the-dict-update-method-interact-with-the-orm

Comment: That's it right there. Could you "answer" rather than "comment" so I could can give you your deserved props?

Comment: If you found the answer by @univerio in the linked Q/A helpful, you can mark/self close this as a duplicate of that and upvote the answer. That way people who find your question can then find the answer as well. Your question will work as a sign post of sorts, which is a good thing – people tend to use different search terms. Your question is also slightly different from that other question, though the answer is the same, so it adds value.